# length of list using foldr in haskell

Tags: haskell

I wrote the following code to calculate length of a list using foldr in haskell. When I compile the code it gives me error as  "myfoldr.hs:3:1: parse error on input `where'". Can anyone please tell me what thing I might be missing or doing wrong in this code ?

```
mylength :: [Int] -> Int
mylength l = foldr f 0 l
where
f :: Int -> Int -> Int
f x y = y+1
```

Comment: In Haskell, whitespace matters. Look at [indentation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation#The_golden_rule_of_indentation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an indentation error: you have to indent the `where` clause, since otherwise Haskell will see the definition of `f` as a separate function. So we can fix it with:

```
mylength :: [Int] -> Int
mylength l = foldr f 0 l
    where f :: Int -> Int -> Int
          f x y = y+1
```

Nevertheless we can still make it more generic: instead of defining it for an `[Int]` list, we can define it over an `[a]` list, with:

```
mylength :: [a] -> Int
mylength l = foldr f 0 l
    where f x y = y+1
```

We can also rewrite `f` as `const (+1)`, so:

```
mylength :: Num n => [a] -> n
mylength = foldr (const (1+)) 0
```

Note that we can apply an *eta-reduction* here: remove `l` both in the head and the body of the `mylength` definition. Or in case we know that the number is also *enumerable*, we can use `succ` instead of `(1+)`:

```
mylength :: (Enum n, Num n) => [a] -> n
mylength = foldr (const succ) 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, now its working fine. Can you explain me why here we need to write 'y+1' instead of 'x+1' even if the base value is in x and we are adding 1 to the base value ?

Comment: @SushodhanVaishampayan: because the signature of `foldr` is `(a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`, so the second parameter is the *accumulator* we update.

Answer (score 5):

In Haskell, whitespace matters - look at the [guide on the Haskell wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation#The_golden_rule_of_indentation).

Formatting your code more correctly gives:

```
mylength :: [Int] -> Int
mylength l = foldr f 0 l
  where
    f :: Int -> Int -> Int
    f x y = y + 1
```

Which [works perfectly](https://ideone.com/CZVd6R) (although the argument `x` to `f` is a bit redundant, you might want to write it as `f _ y = y + 1` instead, or use a lambda expression like `foldr (\_ x -> x + 1) 0 l`).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, now its working fine. Can you explain me why here we need to write 'y+1' instead of 'x+1' even if the base value is in x and we are adding 1 to the base value ?

Comment: @SushodhanVaishampayan `x` is the list element at hand, `y` is the length of the tail. So we want `y+1`. (Note that in `foldl`, instead, we would find the arguments in the other order -- but here we are using `foldr`)